# Easy way to update apache on a server cluster with shared NFS conf?

Tags: amazon-ec2, nfs

we have a server setup where a server cluster connected with a db/files/conf server shared by nfs serve our sites, behind an Elastic Load Balancer at Amazon EC2.

The setup works correctly, but keeping it up to date is becoming like hell, because the apache/php conf that webservers use is shared through NFS. So, if we try to run an apt-get upgrade on a server on the cluster, it will abort it due to the webserver is not able to write back the configuration to the nfs server.

Every time we want to update the machines, or install a package like php-curl, we need to create a new ami, so the changes will reflect on the new launched amis.

Could it be another way of doing the things simpler? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to discover [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) as this is what it's designed for. It'll streamline deploying new packages or updates to the boxes as well as manage the configuration files. You can even automate adding all the proper software and config files to new VMs. Its great for managing clusters and will greatly simplify what your having issues with.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the config back onto local storage then use [cfengine](http://www.cfengine.org/) or [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) to control the config.